# How do I address a bedbug infestation?

Tags: cleaning, pest-control, pest

This bug problem is really stressing me out. I doubt they are bedbugs though because there aren't a lot. I remove 3-8 from my bed a day, and I've read that bedbugs are present in much greater numbers.

They are very small, oval-shaped, and normally have red/brown spots. I'd like to fix the situation as soon as possible since I know they're there and are probably crawling on me while I try to sleep.

Comment: A picture of the bug would help identify them, and might help with figuring out how to remove them.  Your location/climate might also help in identifying the bug.

Comment: just don't let them bite you.

Comment: [Bed bug image](http://www.ca.uky.edu/entomology/entfacts/images/bedbugmp.jpg)

Comment: You can burn them out, crank up the furnace and maintain 120F+ for and hour or so.  Or freeze them out, turn on the AC to below 32F for several days.  I would go with burning them out, since I don't think I would want to live in a below freezing house for days either.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like bed bugs to me.  Have you, or anyone else, noticed bite marks?  Sleep with a flashlight near the bed and if you wake up at night, use that to look for them (too much light will scare them away).

My suggestion is to strip the bed of all linens and wash them (you need heat to kill them, hot water and/or hot air from the dryer).  Remove and check the mattress and box springs and then check the entire bed frame.  Eliminate any paths from the bed frame to the wall or floor (placing the feet of the bed in a bowl of water or some other boundary).  Put the mattress and box springs in a zippered cover.  And finally, use a bed bug spray to kill any that make it through all this.  Note that these things can last a long time, so don't let down your guard for at least a year since you saw the last sign of them.

Answer (score 2):

What you have described is bed bugs, however a pic would confirm this. They are small ovals with brown or reddish rust color. Bed bugs travel vast distances to get to you at night. They are nocturnal hunters that use your CO2 to hone in. While the answers I have read so far are a good way to start the process... know this.

Just cleaning your bed or even your room is not enough. They can fit into extremely tight spaces like anchovies in a can. A neighboring college had a recent infestation, and bug bombing the entire dorm system wasn't enough. They had to call in a specialist to deal with it. He was later on the local news telling people this, "They hide in the same place they were born and never relocate, in this way they are hard to detect, as you can miss their hiding spot for weeks and they will return after every attempt to eradicate them." His advice was to look in the less obvious spots, start with the bed frame, mattress, and the entire room top to bottom. But also check anything you brought into your home recently, plants, pottery, books, stereos, anything. I have a neighbor who bombed their home four or five times in 6 months, but eventual found the last remnants of the infestation in a old pill bottle under the cabinet in the guest bathroom, 20m from their bed room door!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely sounds like bedbugs.  You may just be finding a few random dead ones, or maybe you are just at the beginning of an infestation and they do not exist in large numbers.

The only thing that really kills them is heat and steam cleaning can be effective.  They hide during the day which is why you probably do not see very many actually in the bed.  If you are not noticing the bites it probably just means you are not allergic to the bites.  If they are in your bed and you are the only one sleeping there, you are definitely getting bit.

There are many resources on the web that talk about dealing with bed bugs.  Or you can call a local exterminator who knows how to deal with them.

Answer (score 1):

After you have cleaned up everything,try the following, take four empty tins,fill water upto half level and place four legs of the cot in each of these tins.this will ensure that bugs will not swim across,

Comment: +1 for epicly simple solution for all levels of infestation. If the bugs cannot eat, they die.

Answer (score 1):

Found a good [article](http://www.ca.uky.edu/entomology/entfacts/ef636.asp) on bed bugs (if these really are bed bugs).

> **Treatment Procedures**. Infested and
>   infestation-prone bedding and garments
>   will need to be bagged and laundered
>   (120°F minimum) since these items
>   cannot be treated with insecticides.
>   Another effective and efficient option
>   is to place clothing, toys, shoes,
>   backpacks, etc., in a clothes dryer
>   set at medium to high heat for 10 to
>   20 minutes. This will kill all bed bug
>   life stages and can be done alone or
>   in conjunction with laundering.
>   According to textile experts at the
>   Drycleaning & Laundry Institute
>   (Laurel, MD), most garments designated
>   as ‘dry-clean only’ (e.g., cotton,
>   wool, silk, linen, rayon, nylon, poly
>   blends) will not be harmed provided
>   they are dry before being placed in a
>   clothes dryer at moderate (less than
>   160?F) settings. While dry cleaning
>   procedures also kill bed bugs, there
>   is risk of infesting the establishment
>   when buggy items are de-bagged, tagged
>   and sorted.
>
> Items which cannot be put in a washer
>   or dryer can sometimes be de-infested
>   by wrapping in plastic and placing
>   them outdoors in a hot, sunny
>   location, closed vehicle, etc. for at
>   least a day. If this method is
>   attempted, packing fewer items per bag
>   makes it harder for the bugs to find
>   cooler places to hide. Monitoring with
>   a thermometer is prudent, with a
>   target internal temperature of at
>   least 120°F. Bed bugs also will
>   succumb to cold temperatures below
>   32°F, but the freezing temperatures
>   must be maintained for several days.
>   Consequently, throughout much of the
>   country, heating tends to be a faster,
>   more reliable option than chilling.
>   Attempts to rid an entire dwelling of
>   bed bugs by raising or lowering the
>   thermostat will be unsuccessful,
>   although some companies are having
>   success using supplemental heaters.
>
> General housecleaning measures, such
>   as vacuuming floors and surfaces,
>   seldom reaches the places where bed
>   bugs hide. Targeted vacuuming of
>   infested harborages, however, can help
>   remove some of the bugs before
>   treatment with insecticides. Bed bugs
>   and especially the eggs can be
>   difficult to dislodge. Optimum results
>   will be achieved by moving and
>   scraping the end of the suction wand
>   along infested areas such as seams and
>   fabric folds of beds and sofas, and
>   the perimeter edge of wall-to-wall
>   carpets. Afterward, dispose of the
>   vacuum contents in a sealed trash bag.
>   Some pest control firms also employ
>   commercial steamers or rapid freezing
>   equipment to treat areas where bed
>   bugs are found or suspected. Used
>   correctly, they kill both bugs and
>   eggs on contact. Neither method,
>   however, affords residual protection
>   against bed bugs which may have been
>   missed.   At times it may be necessary
>   to throw out infested items,
>   especially beds and upholstered
>   furniture. Knowledgeable pest control
>   firms are able to advise clients on
>   what can stay and what should go. When
>   infested items are discarded, bagging
>   or wrapping them prevents dislodgement
>   of bugs en route to the Dumpster®.
>
> While the aforementioned measures are
>   helpful, insecticides are important
>   for bed bug elimination. Professionals
>   treat using a variety of low-odor
>   sprays, dusts and aerosols. Baits
>   designed to control ants and
>   cockroaches are ineffective.
>   Application entails treating all areas
>   where the bugs are discovered or tend
>   to crawl or hide. This may take hours
>   of effort and follow-up visits are
>   usually required.   Some bed bug
>   species are parasites of bats or
>   birds, and may bite people if the wild
>   hosts are no longer available. If bat
>   bugs or bird bugs are involved,
>   roosting and nesting sites should be
>   the primary focus of treatment and the
>   animals excluded from the building.